# How to add and adjust a shape during power point slideshow using a vba macro button?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to add basic shapes like rectangle etc. during the full screen slideshow on the current slide. 
I want a macro button on my slide which can do the following after pressing it:-
1. Get x,y coordinates from the cursor position when left click is pressed.
2. Get x,y coordinates from the cursor position when left click is removed.
3. Put these coordinates for adding a shape (with no fill) in the current slide.
4. Adjust the position and size of shape using mouse.
5. Exit the macro when I click somewhere else on slideshow full screen.
The whole process should not exit the full screen slideshow.

Comment: It sounds like you might be new to VBA. If so, that's ambitious starter project. #4 is not possible. We're here to help you debug what you have written. Here's a VBA routine to get the cursor position, to get you going: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/152969/visual-basic-procedure-to-get-set-cursor-position